# Calculate joint probability interchanging the terms

Tags: probability

I've just started to lean probability, and I have found the following very useful book: [OpenIntro Statistics](https://www.openintro.org/stat/textbook.php).

One page 88 you have the table:
[image]

And one page 89 you can find the following two tables:

[image]

If in table 2.14, I want to calculate the joint probability using teen college as the first probability, instead of using parents:

teen college and parents degree
teen college and parents not
teen not and parents degree
teen not and parents not

How can I calculate those joints probabilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the same. The order of the two events in the "and" does not matter. This is because $A\cap B = B\cap A$, so $P(A\text{ and } B) = P(B\text{ and } A)$ (i.e. $P(A\cap B) = P(B\cap A)$).

For example, $P(\texttt{teen not}\text{ and }\texttt{parents not}) = P(\texttt{parents not}\text{ and }\texttt{teen not})$.

Comment: Ok. Then I don't understand example 2.34 (page 88): A teenager is randomly selected from the sample and she did not attend college right after high school. What is the probability that at least one of her parents has a college degree? The book's answer is: P(parents degree given teen not) = 0.141.

Comment: That is different because they are using "**given**". This makes it a *conditional probability*. The formula for the probability of $A$ given $B$ is $\frac{P(A\text{ and }B)}{P(B)}$. Also, the notation for the probability of $A$ given $B$ is $P(A\mid B)$. So $P(A\mid B) = \frac{P(A\text{ and }B)}{P(B)}$.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot. I have understood it now.